# Can I render out a procedural texture onto an image?

Tags: rendering, texturing, image, procedural

...Like if I combine nodes to create a custom texture, can I then output that texture onto an image, so I can use it in other 3d software(unity, unreal etc...)??

Comment: Yes, it's called baking

Comment: @moonboots I think your comment should be an answer. =)

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure what he wants to bake, I'm not experienced in combined baking for example

Comment: Imho, this is not a dup, as nothing mentions in the question we have to start from anything that concerns 3D model and/or uv maps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by rendering the procedural texture defined on a plane.

Define the rendering output to the image resolution you want:

[image]

Place the camera straight above the plane. Set the camera to "orthographic" and its scale to 2 (as the plane is 2 by 2).

[image]

If you want to keep raw colors, set the color management to raw:

[image]

Now you can simply render your image <kbd>F12</kbd> (or using the render menu), and save it to a file.

[image]